# Theano GPU Installation Issue

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

I have installed Anaconda, theano , GPU Toolkit ver 8. I am getting this error.

```
    ERROR: refusing to load cuda driver library because the version is blacklisted.  Versions 373.06 and below are known to be ok.
If you want to bypass this check and force the driver load define GPUARRAY_FORCE_CUDA_DRIVER_LOAD in your environement.
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
```

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question, adding more information, an **actual** question, and perhaps some personal effort you made in order to solve this. Otherwise it could be (heavily) downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

See [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lasagne-users/Fg3o6seitOM) here.

I reinstalled [libgpuarray](http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your cuda driver is faulty. Install another one, preferably 373.06. Using your current driver will result in wrong computations. DO NOT force the driver load